# extract specific line from multiple text files

Tags: windows

I have around 25 000 text files where I want to extract a specific line (255) and create a new text file with the file name the line was extracted from and the content of the line (IMDB ratings)

File names:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
...
...
25000.txt
```

Line content:

```
3.5
7.2
5.8
2.7
```

Output

```
 1.txt,3.5
 2.txt,7.2
 3.txt,5.8
 25000.txt,2.7
```

For some of the text files the line (255) can be empty but I will still need it in the output text file.

Exmaple: (line in the file 43.txt empty)

```
 1.txt,3.5
 2.txt,7.2
 43.txt,
 25000.txt,2.7
```

What would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This is a task that is well suited for almost any of the scripting languages that exist, most of which are available even for Windows.

The task can be accomplished in any of:

- Bash scripting - [www.cygwin.com](https://cygwin.com/install.html) - for windows
- Perl - [Active state Perl](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=active+state+Perl)
- Python - [www.python.org](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=python+2+windows), windows version exists, I recommend 2.7.x for beginners)
- REXX - e.g. [Regina REXX](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=Regina+REXX+windows)

On top of these the task shouldn't be hard in any high-level programming language. It is just barely above beginner level in complexity.

Example: Learn some `C` and compile it with "gcc" in cygwin;
First create a 'line_extractor.c' text file with notepad
Then use `gcc -o line_extractor line_extractor.c`
at the prompt in cmd.exe - Have a go!

You will find loads of examples to pull code from on the net.